# IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'if' statement

Tags: python, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica, opencv

```py
def captura(frame):


    personName = 'Carlos_Espinosa_Herrera'
    dataPath = 'C:/Users/zero_/OneDrive/Documentos/reconocimiento/cio'#Cambia a la ruta donde hayas almacenado Data
    personPath = dataPath + '/' + personName
    if not os.path.exists(personPath):

        print('Carpeta creada: ',personPath)
        os.makedirs(personPath)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
    #cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Video.mp4')
    faceClassif = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades+'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

    while True:
    
      
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        auxFrame = frame.copy()
        faces = faceClassif.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y),(x+w,y+h),(89,44,211),2)
        rostro = auxFrame[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        rostro = cv2.resize(rostro,(150,150),interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
        cv2.imwrite(personPath + '/rotro_{}.jpg'.format(count),rostro)
        count = count + 1
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

    k =  cv2.waitKey(1)

    if k == 27 or count >= 300:
    
    return captura
```

Que tal amigos, soy nuevo en Python y quiero hacer una interfaz donde al momento de dar click en captura me tome cierta serie de fotos , pero al querer hacer la interfaz y la función me marca ese error , el código de reconocimiento ya lo tengo pero lo quiero implementar para la función pero me marca ese error. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme por favor?

Comment: por favor, edita tu pregunta.

Comment: hice lo del return pero me sigue generando el error o tengo mal formulada la funcion?

Comment: Ya que el def esta puesto como texto y no como codigo tengo que preguntar ¿Todo el código esta identado correctamente en tu función? todo el codigo que pusiste debe ir con una identación para hacer referencia que son parte de la función que definiste.

Comment: pues debajo de la funcion esta lo demás y ahora me marca este error   TypeError: captura() missing 1 required positional argument: 'frame'
hasta donde veo creo si esta todo dentro de la funcion

Comment: Está claro, el error te está diciendo que tienes que pasarle un parametro a la funcion captura()

Comment: ¿como que un parametro?

Comment: @CarlosEspinosa al final de la funcion captura tienes un `return captura`, pero no tienes una variable llamada captura en tu funcion no deberia de ser tu return diferente?

Comment: el `return` 4 espacios mas para arriba,no veo ningun otro fallo hay,si eso te da error (`IdentationError`) prueba cambiando esos 4 espacios por tabuladores (tambien se usan de vez en cuando)

Comment: un argumneto es la informacion que se le pasa a la funcion,por ejemplo ```
def x(a):
    return a*2
```,hay no puedes llamar a `x` sin pasarle un argumento `a`,si no que numero multiplica?,en este caso `a` es el argumento,y al llamar la funcion tienes que pasarle un argumento `x(2)` donde 2 toma el valor de `a`

Comment: muchas gracias a todos  ya fue solucionado solo quite el frame de la funcion y posterior a ello agregue un cv2.destroAllWindows() al final de la funcion

Answer (score 0):

```
def captura(frame):


    personName = 'Carlos_Espinosa_Herrera'
    dataPath = 'C:/Users/zero_/OneDrive/Documentos/reconocimiento/cio'#Cambia a la ruta donde hayas almacenado Data
    personPath = dataPath + '/' + personName
    if not os.path.exists(personPath):

        print('Carpeta creada: ',personPath)
        os.makedirs(personPath)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
    #cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Video.mp4')
    faceClassif = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades+'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

    while True:
    
      
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        auxFrame = frame.copy()
        faces = faceClassif.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y),(x+w,y+h),(89,44,211),2)
        rostro = auxFrame[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        rostro = cv2.resize(rostro,(150,150),interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
        cv2.imwrite(personPath + '/rotro_{}.jpg'.format(count),rostro)
        count = count + 1
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

    k =  cv2.waitKey(1)

    if k == 27 or count >= 300:
    
        return captura
```

te faltaba la sangría al final, por eso te dice que no hay nada después del if, ya que al no indicar sangría no podrá ver que viene después de un if dejándolo sin nada, cosa que no se puede hacer en python.